# recovering app data after reinstalling app

Tags: android, google-authenticator

I have a Nexus 5x. I mistakenly removed Google Authenticator, and then re-installed it. all passwords are gone. Is there a way to restore it? from my understanding, they are not backed by Google. I would like to know if there is a way to restore the data from the phone itself. Thank you!
edit:
I found this tool:
https://github.com/dchapkine/extract-google-authenticator-credentials
which allows to withdraw the passwords, unfortunately, it requires the device to be rooted, a process that wipes the data. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `passwords` I'm assuming you mean the shortly generated 6 digit codes?

No, you can't restore those. This is where having those 2FA backup keys would come handy. You would need to login using those, turn off 2FA, and turn it back on again.

It's also possible to contact support of those specific websites and provide info of accounts to prove ownership.